# Realm JNI trace log on android

Tags: java, android, realm

I am getting following exception in my android application :

> 06-23 18:00:49.447 8531-8531/myapp.laugh.russel.debug E/REALM_JNI: Caught exception in collection change callback std::exception

So I want to see the whole exception log.But can't figure out how to turn on the trace logging for REalm JNI

Comment: `RealmLog.setLevel(LogLevel.TRACE)`?

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I was hoping to see more detailed message around this exception I posted above.

Comment: @Jay You do get a Java exception eventually, right?

Comment: @geisshirt mate! setting the trace level wasn't that much helpful.

Comment: @Jay Realm Java swallow exceptions in callbacks since they will hardly make sense (the stack trace will be pretty random). `std::exception` is the generic C++ exception, and it doesn't provide much information. Setting the log level to `Log.VERBOSE` will give you all calls to Realm's C++ code. Looking at the log entries just prior to `Caught exception in collection change callback std::exception` will show us where it went wrong. So please try to set log level and post the last 5-10 entries.